# How to configure AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient endpoint from sbt-dynamodb settings

Tags: scala, sbt, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [sbt-dynamodb](https://github.com/grahamar/sbt-dynamodb) plugin run local AWS DynamoDB for my integration tests. To set up a AWS SDK client I need to provide a client endpoit as

```
val sdkClient = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient(awsCreds)
sdkClient.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000")
```

The plugin allows to configure the DB port number in build.sbt as

```
DynamoDBLocal.Keys.dynamoDBLocalPort := Some(8080)
```

How to access that sbt key (port number) from my test code? To do something like:

```
val dbPort = ???    // get from Keys.dynamoDBLocalPort somehow
sdkClient.setEndpoint("http://localhost:" + dbPort")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I could use [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way already built into sbt-dynamodb.

Comment: sbt-buildinfo is exactly what you want to use.